# identify changes in a specific cell and trigger the function with google apps script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I need to identify changes in the value of specific cells and then update the next blank cell in a specific row. The only thing is that the value changes through an integration with Supermetrics (Google Sheets extension for social media metrics) that is scheduled to run every day. Is there a possible way of doing this? I'm using Google Apps Scripts since this is a sheet from Google Sheets.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
function onChange(e) {
  Logger.log('Change type: ' + e.changeType);

  if (e.changeType === 'OTHER') {
    Logger.log('Edit detected');

    var sheetName = 'base_igbr';
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

    // Get the active range of the edited sheet
    var activeRange = e.source.getActiveRange();
    
    if (activeRange) {
      var editedRow = activeRange.getRow();
      var value = activeRange.getValue();
      Logger.log('Edited row: ' + editedRow + ', Value: ' + value);

      try {
        var lastValueRow4 = sheet.getRange(4, sheet.getLastColumn() - 4).getValue();
        Logger.log('Last value in row 4: ' + lastValueRow4);

        var row4Values = sheet.getRange(4, 5, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 4).getValues()[0];
        Logger.log('Row 4 values: ' + row4Values);

        var nextBlankIndexA2 = row4Values.indexOf('') + 5;
        Logger.log('Next blank index in A2: ' + nextBlankIndexA2);

        var lastValueRow10 = sheet.getRange(10, sheet.getLastColumn() - 4).getValue();
        Logger.log('Last value in row 10: ' + lastValueRow10);

        var row10Values = sheet.getRange(10, 5, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 4).getValues()[0];
        Logger.log('Row 10 values: ' + row10Values);

        var nextBlankIndexA7 = row10Values.indexOf('') + 5;
        Logger.log('Next blank index in A7: ' + nextBlankIndexA7);

        // Check if A2 changed and update row 4 only
        if (editedRow === 2 && value !== lastValueRow4) {
          sheet.getRange(4, nextBlankIndexA2).setValue(value);
        } else if (editedRow === 7 && value !== lastValueRow10) { // Update row 10 only
          sheet.getRange(10, nextBlankIndexA7).setValue(value);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        Logger.log('Error within the try block: ' + error);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(the code is working with manual edits but it doesn't work when this integration makes changes in the cells)

Comment: What you are seeing is the intended behavior.  There is no workaround except to poll that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Since `onChange` is an installable trigger, this means that it has various restrictions, as seen on the Apps Script documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

> Even though installable triggers offer more flexibility than simple
> triggers, they are still subject to several restrictions:
>
> - ...
> - Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling FormResponse.submit() to submit a new form
>   response does not cause the form's submit trigger to run.
> - ...

Since Supermetrics is a Google Sheets Add-on, it is essentially the same as an Apps Script application which means that its "script executions ... do not cause triggers to run", per the documentation above.

I would recommend doing a time-driven trigger to run 5-30 minutes after the Supermetrics functions usually run.

Here is a function that will make that installable trigger (rename your `onChange` function to `checkForChanges`, if you desire to store changes if a user edits then simply call `checkForChanges()` in the `onChange(e)` function):

```js
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkForChanges')
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .create();
}
```